# How is trace message in Azure Application Insights different from log record in Function App Logs table?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I don't understand if there is any duplication of information between the message field in the traces table in Azure Application Insights and the log records that I have in the table Function App Logs that I can export from my Azure Function Apps.

I've tried to look for it in the documentation and did some tests comparing the data but it still hasn't become clear to me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with *Function App Logs*, where can they be found?

Comment: It's the name of the table with logs that we can export in the Diagnostic settings of Azure Function App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is duplication as both Application Insights and the export of Diagnostic settings contains the traces emitted by the function. However, Application Insights captures a lot more details like outgoing dependency calls etc. From that point of view you might consider not using the Diagnostic settings.

Comment: But what is the logic behind this trace message field? Does Application Insights show the log related to the specific trace?

Comment: Application insights is able to connect the trace message to the request and dependencies using the `operation_Id` field. The Function App Logs does not include that data.